# Почему на сервере не пропускает капчу?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

[image: Капча]

Здравствуйте,скрипт с эмуляцией браузера Selenium(Python) работает исправно и пропускает капчу.Если я ставлю скрипт на сервер,то он пишет: "Captcha verification failed".Запускаю селениум в опере.Может у кого-то была такая проблем?Заранее благодарен